# how to split to get in one unit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, string, split

I have the text in a string as shown below

```
NSString *total_duration= 2 days 5 hours 6 min
```

Basically I would like each to get in one unit like  in minute. How can i get this

```
NSInteger *total_duration_inMin=2*24*60+5*60+6
```

Comment: Is there a maximum number of days that are possible?

Comment: @Madhumal Gunetileke nops but there can be only only hours and min..depending on the distance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if the format of your string remains same all the time then you can use this

```
NSArray *array = [total_duration componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

NSInteger a = [[array objectAtIndex:0] intValue] * 24 * 60 + [[array objectAtIndex:2] intValue] * 60 + [[array objectAtIndex:4] intValue];
```

Comment: Little modification:
NSInteger a = [[array objectAtIndex:0] intValue] * 24 * 60 + [[array objectAtIndex:2] intValue] * 60 + [[array objectAtIndex:4] intValue];